# Pentaho: How to replace commas with dots and vice versa(format)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I want to change in number-field format, commas with dots and dots with commas.
Thanks in advance!

[VALUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF7vA.png)  9,795.00

[What I used to format number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ulo.png) ###,###,###.00

And I want it to be like: 9.795,00

Comment: Isn't it typing ###.##0,00 in the format line, two line below the value line ?

Comment: I already tried that but when I do that than it show me empty field on report. @AlainD

Answer (score 1):

At the end I left formation like it is (###,###,###.00), because formatting depends on localization. I will set hardcoded localization value through java and when calling report it will forward french or german localization.

Comment: if you are getting the values from database,rather you can simply handle this on database level. for example : mysql has a format function where you can specify the details, check sample,       FORMAT(1111.1111,2,@p_locale)
       values,decimal_places,language